# Can I force python to use /dev/random for os.urandom?

Tags: python, linux

I have a Python script which calls `os.urandom(n)` but I want the script to take `/dev/random` as its source instead of `/dev/urandom`.

I'm wondering if this is possible:

- ideally, either remap the device itself within Python, or remap `os.urandom` to a function of my own which would read from `/dev/random`, thereby leaving the script itself unchanged,
- less ideally, create and add `os.random` to the `os` module, or create the function somewhere else entirely, requiring a change in the script,
- also acceptable would be something more extreme like to run Python in a VM which uses `/dev/random` in place of `/dev/urandom` system-wide.

What's the best (i.e. least invasive to the application script) way of achieving this?

(I am not a Python programmer so please supply an implementation if a new Python function needs to be written.)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the question is **can I make *existing* calls to os.urandom use /dev/random instead**?

Comment: No, `os.urandom()` *always* will use `/dev/urandom` on Linux, read directly instead. Not that that is a good idea, mind.

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate because the *direct* answer is *No, you can't do that* which is not helpful either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters did you read the whole question? The question you have linked to doesn't tell me how to extend the `os` interface (one alternative) or whether I can remap the device system-wide e.g. in a VM. By trying to close this question you are leaving other avenues unexplored.

Comment: You **cannot** extend it. Really, the whole answer really is *No you cannot do that*. Remapping `/dev/urandom` to use `/dev/random` instead is going to hurt you, don't go there at all.

Comment: Nevertheless *this is not the same question*. Please withdraw your hasty close request and leave room for someone to suggest an outside-of-Python solution.

Comment: If you need cryptographically secure random data that doesn't reuse entropy, use [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) instead; it provides you with a [`Crypto.Random` object](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/#crypto-random).

Comment: You are free to nominate for a re-open, but do include what problem you are trying to solve first, as this looks to me to be a [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Thanks for the Crypto.Random hint, but *I'm not a Python programmer* -- substituting `x=os.urandom(n)` with `x=Crypto.random.get_random_bytes(n)` is giving me "not defined" errors. I'm stumbling around with `import` at the moment, can you please go one step further and actually show me the solution?

Comment: `import Crypto.Random`, then `x = Crypto.Random.get_random_bytes(n)`.

Comment: That runs, thanks but *it does not block*. It must be either using /dev/urandom under the hood or doing something similar itself. What's the real solution? Please reopen this question!

Comment: PyCrypto uses a [Fortuna PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_%28PRNG%29) to provide you with cryptographically strong random data, *backed* by `/dev/urandom`. It comes out stronger than `/dev/random` in [this lab test of RNGs](http://www.cacert.at/cgi-bin/rngresults).